# Why does the argument for printf from ctypes need a newline at the end

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I'm following the docs/tutorial here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.htmlpython3.8

In section "Calling Functions Continued" it has a snippet for running printf. I played around with it a bit, and I can't understand why the first statement below prints only 5 and not Hello? Why is the newline needed? (update: also why are the orders sometimes different i.e. "5 Hello" vs "Hello 6")

```
>>> libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
>>> libc.printf
<_FuncPtr object at 0x7f68e4d61880>
>>> printf = libc.printf
>>> printf(b"Hello")
5
Hello>>> printf(b"Hello","")
5
Hello>>> printf(b"Hello %S\n","World!")
Hello World!
13
>>> printf(b"Hello\n","")
Hello
6
```

I suppose it might have something to do with this statement made on the same page:

> Note that printf prints to the real standard output channel, not to
> sys.stdout, so these examples will only work at the console prompt,
> not from within IDLE or PythonWin:

But I can't really understand this statement, I always thought sys.stdout was the real system output channel. (perhaps these applications set it to something different)?

setup: python 3.8 running inside a linux docker container on a Mac

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf. Also check [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not printing a newline is because it's Python's native `print` function that normally adds a newline.  The `libc` `printf` implementation (what you would call if you were writing in C) does not print a newline at the end. You must explicitly add it.

As for the `sys.stdout` vs "real standard out", "real standard out" writes to file descriptor 1.  `sys.stdout` ultimately does as well, but it goes through some code that the IDLE/PythonWin likely capture and process.  So using `printf` would circumvent those things, and therefore wouldn't show up.  Not sure how it's implemented so that it doesn't, but that's the difference between them.

Comment: thanks, why does it sometimes happen that "number" is first and the words come second i.e. "5 Hello" vs. "Hello 6"

Comment: It's just a race condition between the underlying printf and Python's REPL.  The REPL (the thing showing you the >>>) is printing the return of ``printf`` which is the number of bytes printed.  Then ``printf`` is writing to stdout, which the REPL is also printing.  It's not going to be completely serial because you're dealing with IO, which is slow and buffered.